# Loop through mysql registries and printing them

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database with some tables, I did a php script that will print a table like this:

```
[user name]

[field 1][field 2][field 3]

[value 1][value 1][value 1]
```

...etc, containing "n" values from each field corresponding to the user name.

but what I want is to display this table for **each** user, a loop printing this table for every user in my database. I know I will have to do a loop before the  tag right? but I don't know which conditions this loop will have,someone could help me showing me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Note that You'll have to add database connection information and change database and table names.

```
$db_name = 'database';
$table_name = 'table';
mysql_connect() or die("MySQL Error: ". mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("MySQL Error: ". mysql_error());
$columns_q = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table_name");
if(!$columns_q){
    die("Error fetching columns $table_name: " . mysql_error());
}
echo '<table><tr>';
while($column = mysql_fetch_assoc($columns_q)){
    echo '<td>' . $column['Field'] . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
$fields_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table_name");
if(!$fields_q){
    die("Error fetching fields $table_name: " . mysql_error());
}
while($fields = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields_q)){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```